# Keycodes map to wrong keys

Tags: java, android, gamepad

I'm working on an Android app/semi-game (API 19-23, Java) and I used [this](https://developer.android.com/training/game-controllers/controller-input.html) website to help me handle controller input. Overall it looks pretty similar to what the website says for "Process Gamepad Button Presses":

```
public boolean processKeyEvent(int keyCode, String name) {        
    boolean handled = false;
    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BUTTON_L1:
            ...
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BUTTON_R1:
            ...
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BUTTON_A:
            ...
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BUTTON_B:
            ...
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BUTTON_X:
            ...
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BUTTON_Y:
            ...
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BUTTON_START:
            ...
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
            ...
    }
    if(handled) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

and:

```
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(android.view.KeyEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        handled = script.processKeyEvent(event.getKeyCode(), event.getDevice().getName());
    }

    if (handled) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }
}
```

It does return the right keycodes (according to [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/KeyEvent.java) list), so:

- L1: 102
- R1: 103
- A: 96
- B: 97
- X: 99
- Y: 100
- Start: 108
- Back: 4

The problem is that half of the buttons not only activate through their right case but also other ones, which then has side effects of course:

- B activates: X, Y, Start
- X: Y, Start
- Y: Start
- R1: A
- L1: R1, A

At first I thought that maybe the controller (SteelSeries Stratus XL for Android) had broken but I already checked with a second one (MogaPro Power) and I got the same results with it.

Has anyone else experienced this before? Any idea what I could try to fix this?

Comment: Looking at the key codes, a code above seems to activate those below... Could you be missing `break;` statements?

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 *facepalm* I didn't have the ones for the five keys right at the end but in an "else" part. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a quick investigation it looks like you are missing some `break;` statements from your cases which results in flow-trough.